# How to handle dependencies while creating own node module in types

Tags: node.js, typescript, ionic2, node-modules, package.json

I am trying to create and publish node module in typescript. My library has some dependencies which I have added in the package.json.

```
{
    "name": "my-unite-framework",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "description": "Can log \"hello world\" and \"goodbye world\" to the console!",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.6",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^4.2.0",
        "@ionic-native/network": "^3.4.4",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.0.1",
        "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
        "ionic-cache": "^2.0.4",
        "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
        "rxjs": "5.1.1"
    }
}
```

But when I published and installed it in the new project, the node_modules dependencies get installed in `my-unite-framework` folder itself, instead of installing in the project folder.

So how can I installed these dependencies in only in project `node_module` folder?

Comment: npm should do that by default - what version of npm are you using? The latest version (v4) will install the dependencies in the top level `node_modules` folder, unless there is a version conflict between the top-level project's dependency and you module's dependency.

Comment: @AJRichardson ohh! so it worked like this. I have npm version 4.2.0 and have some conflicts between the dependencies. But whenver I create a new project it takes the latest version of the npm module whereas my module will take old one, so how can I prevent it ?